# Can a java exploit circumvent browser plug in permission?

Tags: exploit, vulnerabilities, java

Since Java 7 is vulnerable i am asking myself if the vulnerability is circumventing the plug in permission of any given browser.

For example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn1Rbnidhl8 here you see an exploit in which the user needs to give the plug in permissions to run.

Does the current exploit act without being recognized at all?

PS: Since i am using NoScript i feel pretty safe to not get affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Java WebStart runs at Medium Integrity.

In order to protect yourself from this exploit, you should immediately disable Java in all of your browsers and wait for a patch to be released.

You should also make sure that any anti-virus software you have is fully up-to-date. This will reduce, but not eliminate the risk that you are successfully exploited using this vulnerability in Java.

Comment: @Moab : Java is rarely used on websites except for casual gaming websites, and special purpose websites like http://time.gov/ . it is not used on 95% of websites, and is not used on SuperUser. You might be confusing "Java" with "JavaScript", which are two very different technologies with a similar name.

Comment: My bad, always get those 2 mixed up!